# Do I need to manually release CFStringRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, core-foundation

Can you please tell me which is the right way and why in non ARC world.

```
+ (NSString *)getUUID {
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
CFRelease(theUUID);
return [(NSString*) string autorelease];
}
```

or

```
+ (NSString *)getUUID {
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
CFRelease(theUUID);
return (NSString*)string;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using NSUUID instead.

Comment: @Catfish_Man I like your way but only problem is NSUUID was added to Foundation in iOS 6. My app target is iS 5.0. So I have to CFUUIDRef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers are correct for manual retain counting.  When you come to your senses ;^) and switch to ARC, you won't be able to send `autorelease`.  Instead, under ARC, do it this way:

```
+ (NSString *)getUUID {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return CFBridgingRelease(string);
}
```

A `CFBridgingRelease` is equivalent to a `CFRelease` for the purposes of balancing the +1 retain count returned by `CFUUIDCreateString`, but also returns a still-valid reference that ARC will take care of releasing.

Comment: Under ARC (or really under non-ARC), I would do it this way: + (NSString *) UUID { return [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]; }

Comment: @Catfish_Man I like your way but only problem is NSUUID was added to Foundation in iOS 6. My app target is iS 5.0. So I have to CFUUIDRef.

Comment: I thought this was a non ARC question? Is this still valid outside of ARC?

Comment: Yes, it's a non-ARC question. I added this answer for the benefit of people who find this question and are using ARC, since the title and tags don't mention ARC or MRC.  I don't know why this was chosen as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

CFStrings do need to be released. The first way is correct because CFString is [toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) with NSString, and thus can safely be autoreleased like an NSString.

Answer (score 2):

Your method should return an autoreleased object so the client is responsible for obtaining ownership over the object, and it won't leak if they ignore the return value.

Number one is the correct method. The `CFString` is created, +1 retain count, autoreleased and returned for the client. The cast to `NSString` does not affect the retain count.

In the second method the `CFString` is created, +1 retain count, but never balanced with a release or autorelease.

Comment: @Inafziger I definitely agree in general, but this post is using the correct relative "+1" notation (= The retain count is unbalanced due to there being "one too many" retains).

Comment: call it "reference count"

Comment: @lnafziger I am indicating the delta with +1

Comment: @MatthiasBauch everyone knows what im talking about, and thats what it is referred to in code. Outside of the context of apple frameworks I would

Comment: @lnafziger I meant everyone knows what im talking about when I say "retain count" instead of "reference count"

Comment: @lnafziger I wouldn't say "very different" in this concrete example, but I understand the importance of thinking in deltas rather than absolute retain count.

Comment: @lnafziger ok done. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.