# CFStringRef release gives bad access when it is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, addressbook, cfstring

```
ABMultiValueRef phonesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phonesRef); i++)
    {
        CFStringRef currentPhoneLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phonesRef, i);
        CFStringRef currentPhoneValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonesRef, i);

        if (currentPhoneLabel != nil && currentPhoneValue != nil)
        {
            if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
            {
                [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue forKey:@"workNumber"];
            }

            if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABHomeLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
            {
                [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue forKey:@"homeNumber"];
            }
        }
        else if (currentPhoneValue != nil && currentPhoneLabel == nil)
        {
            [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue forKey:@"workNumber"];
        }

        CFRelease(currentPhoneLabel);
        CFRelease(currentPhoneValue);
    }
    CFRelease(phonesRef);
```

Here is my code for importing contact phones into my ios app, but                    when currentPhoneLabel is nil xocde for CFRelease(currentPhoneLabel).
I don't know why is it happening.
Any help would be much appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: I refer from below stackoverflow answers which about memory release , by your crash log, if there is no data in that label, how it release memory? it should be crash right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959760/do-i-need-to-manually-release-cfstringref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have guards in other places in the code, so you just need to add a guard on every call to `CFRelease()` as well:

```
if (currentPhoneLabel != NULL)
    CFRelease(currentPhoneLabel);
// etc.
```